# Stored Procedure - Linq to Entities - Support Join (Includes() equivelant)

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

I'm new to stored procedures. I've created the following simple stored procedure:

```
USE db
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSearchResults
    @BatchId NVARCHAR(20)
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchResult sr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SearchResultItem sri ON sri.SearchResultID = sr.SearchResultID
    WHERE sr.BatchID = @BatchId AND (sri.Name = 'sales_rank' OR sri.Name = 'sale_price' OR sri.Name = 'list_price')
GO
```

I am currently calling this stored procedure in my C# application as follows:

```
public List<SearchResult> GetSearchResult(string batchId, ModelContainer ctn)
{
    var parameters = new object[] { new SqlParameter("@BatchId", batchId)};

    List<SearchResult> searchResults = ctn.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchResult>("exec GetSearchResults @BatchId", parameters).ToList();

    return searchResults;
}
```

This is great, however my only issue is that it does not load the SearchResultItem (child) table, which I also need (see left outer join in stored procedure).

In my edmx model, in the Function Imports section, I have tried setting the stored procedure to return a collection of 'Complex' and 'Entities'. Neither of these have worked.

Could anyone offer any advice?

EDIT - Using Entity Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use multiple select statements within your stored procedure - one for each entity type to return, then use `ObjectContext.Translate<T>(...)` with a `DbReader` resulting from the `DbCommand` execution to import the results into your `ObjectContxt`/`DbContext`.  The navigation properties will be hooked up automatically.  [Read this to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)

Important note: the fields returned by the select statements must match the property names of the entity classes exactly

Update: since you're using EDMX, you can alter the EDMX to do the importing for you (linked page demonstrates this as well)